# Docker Failed to start on Windows 10 Enterprise VM

Tags: docker, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, docker-machine

I am trying to install Docker Desktop in windows 10 Enterprise VM. Also.I have enabled Hyper-V. 
I have gone through many articles but couldn't fix it. 
Please if anyone can help me on below error:

Below are VM Details:

Windows 10 Enterprise
RAM: 4 GB
System Type: 64-bit OS, x64 based processor

Docker version: 2.2.0.5.

virtualization is enabled still I face same issue. Enabled 'Use Intel VT-x/AMD-V for instruction set virtualization...' .

[Error  ] Unable to start Hyper-V VM: Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualizationException: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.

Failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 109C9013-5F42-4EF4-A80C-AE69E1372AFC)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 109C9013-5F42-4EF4-A80C-AE69E1372AFC). ---> Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.VirtualizationOperationFailedException: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.

Comment: Have you enable virtualization features on CPU as well?

Comment: Hi @vonPryz I tried enabling virtualization through Update & security-> Recovery-> Advanced Startup option is not enabled. Is there any other way in windows 10 VM to verify and enable virtualization?

Comment: Questions about how to configure OS are better suited at SuperUser. That being said, CPU virtualization features are configured in BIOS, not (only) on Windows.

Comment: Hi @vonPryz after virtualization is enabled still I face same issue. Enabled 'Use Intel VT-x/AMD-V for instruction set virtualization...' .

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you try to get [nested virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization) running. In case of Hyper-V in Hyper-V you need to enable that using

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName DockerDesktopVM -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

Not sure if even then you need to have some Intel CPU. Its possible, that that has [changed](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/can-amd-run-nested-virtualization/014c3d89-e616-45ee-a710-07d79d629d22).

Docker on Windows needs an [additional virtualization layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers) to your virtualized windows. That is not enabled by default.